# What is the term used to describe multiple domains pointing to the same web service?

Tags: url

Where the same site is available via

```
account761.Mainsite.com/
```

OR

```
Mycustomdomain.com/
```

And of course has the exact same modules and sections and pages under these "roots"

Back in the day, communitystarterkit supported this scenario and had a few site hosted/running this way and now trying to do something similar with asp.net mvc3 but can't locate it as I am not sure what this "thing" is called :)

UPDATE - all the content on the site is accessible via both url's and looks the same unless chosen to look different via different templates

Comment: wonder whatz the programming part in this question !

Comment: @V4Vendetta - need a name so can search for it in a existing CMS to use as a baseline for further enhancement ! Everthing in programming need not be writing If/Then/Else or Insert/Update/Delete ! I hope programming 101 still has 80/20 rule - 80% design and ***20%*** coding

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you'd call that - but it's a DNS and IIS setting. You set both names to point to the same server in DNS, and then use Host Headers to tell IIS the site to serve. It's similar to having www.site.com and site.com both serve the same website.

Code-wise, I'd imagine you could do a check on Request.Url to customize the experience depending on what domain name was used. Again, not familiar with this being called a "feature" in any particular framework - but I'd guess any docs would have to reference "host headers" for configuration.

Edit: I got a bit confused, because I didn't quite grok the multiple clients part of your questions - but I think I get it now. You want 1 application to serve different clients, with potentially per-site customizations based on the URL. This is called multi-tenancy. It happens to be (usually) implemented the way I specified above, but the overall concept of a single website codebase serving multiple clients is called a multi-tenant architecture (vs multi-instance, which has as many installations as clients).

Comment: correct, The Q is not how to do it but what it's called for a comparison of existing open source projects ! as stated above, did it earlier with communitystarterkit and it worked wonderfully! now moving to mvc razor and looking for an existing solution(s) that has this built-in if possible along with other features rather than reinventing the wheel completely

Comment: @Kumar - Multi tenancy

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to this as a parked domain... mycustomdomain.com is a parked domain which points to the real content hosted at mainsite.com/account761/.

Comment: Not a parked domain, both sites are live and active and render the same content !

Comment: A parked domain will render the same content! Look it up: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/what-is-a-parked-domain-how-do-i-create-and-delete-one

Comment: interesting, it IS different in some places from domain parking, though that terminology has some traction, it's not quite settled yet ! google search for parked domain has this http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/ParkedDomains just below the next result for hostgator, where it uses the term parked domain but explains it to be the same as domain parking! but it's a good start for my quest

Answer (score 0):

A lot of [Software as a Service (SAAS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) sites operate this way, however, all that is happening here is the site knows to render a certain template/layout based on a url or subdomain that is being passed to the site.

Comment: correct and as stated above, have done it before with communitystarterkit, the issue is what it's called to compare mvc razoe projects and if they support it ! rather than try and explain it and all it's glory which has not been entirely smooth so far ! looking for the right term that'll explain it in 1/2 words/phrases leaving no scope for confusion, perhaps SAAS is the right term !